# CAT as arguments to Bash Script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell, cat

I have a script that I execute by:

```
./myscript.sh database table
```

This script receives two values $1 and $2

I also have a textfile.txt containing something like this:

```
database1 table1  
database2 table2  
database3 table3  
database4 table4  
...  
...  
...
```

I would like to pass the data contained in textfile.txt to my script in one command from the shell. I was thinking something like this:

```
./myscript.sh | cat textfile.txt
```

But does not work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You're piping it wrong. The stuff you want to pipe to your script comes before the script: `cat textfile.txt | ./myscript.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a loop:

```
while read -r db table; do
    ./myscript.sh $db $table
done < textfile.txt
```